# Unable to multiply two string values in swift

Tags: json, swift, string, floating-point

I am getting float value in string format from JSON like below

JSON:

```
{
 "result": {

  "conversion_factor": {
        "conv_factor": "0.820000"
    }
    "search_result": [
        {
         "service_details": [
                {
                  "standard_rate_in_usd": "10.00",
```

**now i need to multiply `conv_factor * standard_rate_in_usd`**

**code:** with this code only first value coming correct remaining showing wrong why?

```
let indexData = searchResult?.result?.search_result?[indexPath.row]

if let servDetls = indexData?.service_details{

for oneSerdet in servDetls{
    
    var stringPrice: String?
    
    if var priceVal = Float(oneSerdet.standard_rate_in_usd!), var convVal = Float((searchResult?.result?.conversion_factor?.conv_factor)!) {
        stringPrice = String(priceVal * convVal)
    }
    else{
        stringPrice = ""
    }
    cell.priceLbl.text = "£ \(stringPrice ?? "") \(currData)"
}
}
```

Comment: You have edited your code and are now asking for help with a different problem. Now it sounds like you are trying to set up all your cells with one block of imperative code? Are you trying to populate table view/collection view cells with this data? You need to provide more context to your (new) question.

Comment: How do you get from your JSON data to searchResult? Is `searchResult` the object you get back from parsing your JSON? have you set up an object that conforms to Codable in order to convert the JSON to an object? We can't help unless you tell us what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to floats:

```
let convResult = Float(oneSerdet.standard_rate_in_usd) * 
Float(searchResult?.result?.conversion_factor?.conv_factor)
```

Comment: error: `Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Float' operands` 2) error: No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: try `Double` instead of `Float`

Comment: how are you decoding the JSON file?

Comment: I have edited my JSON structure and added my full code.. please take a look and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will resolves your issue

```
if let conv_factor = oneSerdet.conv_factor,
    let factor = Double(conv_factor),
    let standard_rate_in_usd = oneSerdet.standard_rate_in_usd,
    let usd = Double(standard_rate_in_usd) {
    print(factor*usd)
    cell.priceLbl.text = "\(factor*usd)"
}else{
    cell.priceLbl.text = ""
    print("Unreachable")
}
```

Comment: I have edited my JSON structure and added my full code.. please take a look and guide me.

Comment: when I debug.. then oneSerdet.standard_rate_in_usd! not coming correct in my above code... why? where am i wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

1. Your construct `searchResult?.result?.conversion_factor?.conv_factor` evaluates to an Optional String: `String?`.
2. You can't multiply strings. Strings are not numeric. You need to convert your string to a Double. But the Double initializer that takes a string also returns an Optional (since "Apple", for example, can't be converted to a Double.

Here is some sample code that will take 2 Optional Strings, try to convert them to Doubles, and multiples them.

```
let xString: String? = "123.456"
let yString: String? = "2.0"

let x = xString.map { Double($0) ?? 0 } ?? 0.0
let y = yString.map { Double($0) ?? 0 } ?? 0.0

let result: Double = x * y
print(result)
```

That outputs

> 246.912

Comment: I have edited my JSON structure and added my full code.. please take a look and guide me

Comment: if i use ur code hits an error bcz of json structure

Comment: when I debug.. then `oneSerdet.standard_rate_in_usd!` not coming correct in my above code... why? where am i wrong

Comment: I answered your original question about converting Optional Strings to floating point so you could multiply them. You have not provided your JSON decoding code, so we have no way to help you with that part.